# How do I resolveClass without importing the type first?

Tags: haxe

*Note that I'm using Haxe 3.0.1 on Linux targeting Neko.*

Consider the following code:

```
var classObject = Type.resolveClass("Foo");
```

Assuming that I have a class `Foo` in the same package as this code, this should give me a `Class` object with info about `Foo` in it. However, in my tests it is only working if I `import Foo;` first. If I do not import `Foo` then `resolveClass` returns  `null` instead. This is strange to me.

I noticed that the [Haxe API](http://haxe.org/api/type) docs state:

> The class must have been compiled to be accessible and if the Class is not in the same package, the full "dot path" must be given as part of the string.

But it is not clear to me what "must have been compiled to be accessible" means in this context or how it applies to my problem.

So, do I really need to `import` every class that I might want to resolve, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should give `Type.resolveClass` the fully qualified name of the class. I.e. `pack.subpack.AClass`.

Secondly, you may use `--macro include("pack")`. Which the `include` function is a method from [`haxe.macro.Compiler`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Compiler.html#include). `--macro` by default looks into that class for methods.

Lastly, the `import my.package.*` statement in haxe is lazy. It tell the compiler to resolve types in `my.package`, but not really import everything in `my.package` in the beginning.

Comment: The docs mention that you only need to use the fully qualified name if the target class is not in the same package as the calling code. In any case, in this example `Foo` is in the empty package so "Foo" **is** the fully qualified name.

Comment: I guess the doc you referred to is http://haxe.org/api/type , which is somehow outdated... The updated one is at http://api.haxe.org/Type.html#resolveClass . With simple testing, I confirmed the fully qualified name is required. It is just for your case `Foo` is in the top-level package, it happens to be fully qualified.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried using `--macro include("my.package")` and I ran into a separate problem which I've asked about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391833/macro-include-is-recursively-including-packages-not-appropriate-for-build-targ).

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to ...
but you can batch it with haxe.macro.ImportAll("package")

Comment: Are you sure this class exists in Haxe 3.0.1? It is not listed in the [Haxe API docs](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/index.html). Haxe 3 introduced the `import my.package.*` syntax for importing a whole package, but I've tried it and it does not resolve my problem.