# Macro --include is recursively including packages not appropriate for build target

Tags: macros, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm building a game using the HaxeFlixel lib. In one part of my code I'm dynamically resolving classes via `Type.resolveClass()`. In order to avoid having to reference every potential class individually, I tried to use `--macro include()` by adding this to my `project.xml`:

```
<haxeflag name="--macro" value="include('my.pack')" />
```

This worked fine when compiling against the Flash target, but when I try to compile against neko I get:

```
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\flixel/3,0,4/flixel/FlxG.hx:3: characters 7-34 : You can not access the flash package while targeting neko (for flash.display.DisplayObject)
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\flixel/3,0,4/flixel/FlxSprite.hx:3: characters 7-18 :     referenced here
source/objects/enemies/Bat.hx:3: characters 7-23 :     referenced here
--macro:1: character 0 :     referenced here
```

It looks like the include macro is recursively including everything that my classes imported, including stuff that isn't appropriate for the neko target. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: This is an interesting problem! But I'm not sure why you need to have that include statement. Based on your question, it's totally unrelated to Type.resolveClass(). Could you give some more information? It seems like this should work without the haxeflag.

Comment: @SteveRichey Apparently if you don't specifically reference a type (or use this macro to include it) then it won't be compiled and thus won't be available to resolve. See my previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323768/how-do-i-resolveclass-without-importing-the-type-first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenFL requires `--macro allowPackage("flash")` to work, which suppress the `You can not access the flash package...` error.

It looks like `include` is called before `allowPackage`, so you may manually call `allowPackage` before `include`:

```
<haxeflag name="--macro" value="allowPackage('flash')" />
<haxeflag name="--macro" value="include('my.pack')" />
```